# Symfony 4 getting multiple cache.WARNING Failed to save key

Tags: caching, symfony4

I've been setting up both skeleton and web-skeleton new projects using the latest version of symfony.
In both of them, but not in the symfony-demo application, I am getting tons of warning lines on the logs whenever i take any action in the apps.

The warnings show both while running the web-server or Apache.

log warnings all look like the following all of them pointing to fylesystemCommonTrait.php:

**cache.WARNING: Failed to save key ..... (ErrorException(code: 0): touch(): Utime failed: No such file or directory at ..... vendor\symfony\cache\Traits\FilesystemCommonTrait.php:90**

In crud operations i usally get hundreds of warnings each time.

Sample logs from a simple hello controller:
*[2018-03-25 21:03:24] request.INFO: Matched route "hello". {"route":"hello","route_parameters":{"_controller":"App\Controller\DefaultController::hello","_route":"hello"},"request_uri":"http://localhost/symfony/symwebcrud/public/","method":"GET"} []
[2018-03-25 21:03:24] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []
[2018-03-25 21:03:24] cache.WARNING: Failed to save key "%5BApp%5CController%5CDefaultController%5D%5B1%5D" (array) {"key":"%5BApp%5CController%5CDefaultController%5D%5B1%5D","type":"array","exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): touch(): Utime failed: No such file or directory at E:\Development\Symfony\symwebcrud\vendor\symfony\cache\Traits\FilesystemCommonTrait.php:90)"} []
[2018-03-25 21:03:24] cache.WARNING: Failed to save key "%5B%5BC%5DApp%5CController%5CDefaultController%5D%5B1%5D" (integer) {"key":"%5B%5BC%5DApp%5CController%5CDefaultController%5D%5B1%5D","type":"integer","exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): touch(): Utime failed: No such file or directory at E:\Development\Symfony\symwebcrud\vendor\symfony\cache\Traits\FilesystemCommonTrait.php:90)"} []
[2018-03-25 21:03:24] cache.WARNING: Failed to save key "%5BApp%5CController%5CDefaultController%23hello%5D%5B1%5D" (array) {"key":"%5BApp%5CController%5CDefaultController%23hello%5D%5B1%5D","type":"array","exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): touch(): Utime failed: No such file or directory at E:\Development\Symfony\symwebcrud\vendor\symfony\cache\Traits\FilesystemCommonTrait.php:90)"} []
[2018-03-25 21:03:24] cache.WARNING: Failed to save key "%5B%5BC%5DApp%5CController%5CDefaultController%23hello%5D%5B1%5D" (integer) {"key":"%5B%5BC%5DApp%5CController%5CDefaultController%23hello%5D%5B1%5D","type":"integer","exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): touch(): Utime failed: No such file or directory at E:\Development\Symfony\symwebcrud\vendor\symfony\cache\Traits\FilesystemCommonTrait.php:90)"} []*

Answer (score 10):

Make sure you have APC(u) enabled for the CLI.

Set `apc.enable_cli = 1` in your config file for PHP's CLI, eg. `/etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini`